# Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-00936: missing expression ): JDBC connection error in Jmeter3.0

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

I am running one jmeter script to read data from Database (using JDBC Request). Here I am getting following error if I am running script in Jmeter3.0.

> Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-00936: missing expression
>   )

But same script is running fine with jmeter2.13.

Do I need to change any property values?

Comment: any feedback on answer ? thx If ok you should accept it and upvote

Answer (score 0):

Just modify Validation query in [JDBC Connection Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) to select 1 from DUAL as per documentation:

> A simple query used to determine if the database is still responding. This defaults to 'SELECT 1' which is suitable for many databases. However some may require a different query; for example Oracle requires something like 'SELECT 1 FROM DUAL'. Note this validation query is used on pool creation to validate it even if "Test While Idle" suggests query would only be used on idle connections. This is DBCP behaviour.